# Report Subtotal Amount not displaying correctly

Tags: custom-report-type, bug

Trying to find a solution for why the subtotal (and by extension all formulas based off this) are not displaying the correct total. Correct total for this column should be 71. It displays 12. Any ideas why?[image]

For the column "Gave this year and last year", there is a formula that returns either a 1 or 0. The summarized results and then placed in a separate formula to calculate donor retention. The issue is that "subtotal" only states a result of 12 (while there are 71 (1)s present on the report) which heavily skews the results of the next formula.

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. We'll need more info as to why you expect 71.  Use [edit]

Comment: For the column "Gave this year and last year", there is a formula that returns either a 1 or 0. The summarized results and then placed in a separate formula to calculate donor retention. The issue is that "subtotal" only states a result of 12 (while there are 71 (1)s present on the report) which heavily skews the results of the next formula.